# Decoding JSON in Java

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

im really new to java through Eclipse android, and im trying to decode this line of JSON

```
{"FullName":"bobby Bloggs"}
```

But when i try to put it into an array through

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(httpData);
JSONObject feedObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("FullName");
```

I hit an exception of

```
org.json.JSONException: Value bobby Bloggs at FullName of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to read a String, since {} within the JSON means it is an object. Everything between "" means it's a string. true/false a boolean (getBoolean) and numbers are an Integer (getInteger). Since you want the String you need to use.

```
String FullName = JSONObject.getString("FullName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get JSONObject out of JSON Object  i.e jsonObject.getJSONObject("FullName");  and again assigning to JSONObject.

As suggested by Emanuel use getString to get the data of "FullName" as and assign to a String.

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(httpData);
String FullName = jsonObj.getString("FullName"); 
will work.